# A sum involving permutation

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, power-series

Does there exist a nice closed form formula for the sum 
$$\sum_{k=0}^m P(m,k)x^k$$
where $P(m,k)=C(m,k)*k!$, $C(m,k)$ being the "m choose k" number. 
Formula given by Maple 11 is complicated. I thought there may be an easier one.
Of course
$$\sum_{k=0}^m C(m,k)x^k=(1+x)^m.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom mkk!x^k&=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}x^k\\
&=m!\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{x^{m-j}}{j!}\\
&=m!x^mS_m\left(\frac 1x\right),
\end{align}
where $S_n(t):=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{t^j}{j!}$. But the $S_n$ are hard to simplify.

Comment: Your variables in your definition of $S_n$ seem to be mixed up...

Comment: We could use the integral representation

$$
S_m(t) = \frac{e^t}{m!} \int_t^\infty u^m e^{-u}\,du = \frac{e^t}{m!}\Gamma(m+1,t)
$$

to get

$$
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom mkk!x^k = e^{1/x} x^m \Gamma(m+1,1/x),
$$

where $\Gamma(s,t)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).